# Add subdocument array element to subdocument array element in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is this possible?
I have a collection C, with an array of attributes A1.
Each attribute has an array of subattributes A2.

How can I add a subdocument to a specific C.A1 subdocument ?

Comment: A before and after example document illustrating what you're looking for would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example.

```
db.docs.insert({_id: 1, A1: [{A2: [1, 2, 3]}, {A2: [4, 5, 6]}]})
```

If you know the index of the subdocument you want to insert, you can use dot notation with the index (starting from 0) in the middle:

```
db.docs.update({_id: 1}, {$addToSet: {'A1.0.A2': 9}})
```

This results in:

```
{
    "A1" : [
        {
            "A2" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                9
            ]
        },
        {
            "A2" : [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ]
        }
    ],
    "_id" : 1
}
```

Comment: "If you know the index of the subdocument you want to insert, " -- how would you know the index if you're inserting it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. If you post an example I can show you more specifically what the update query would look like. But here's a shot:

```
db.c.update({ A1: value }, { $addToSet: { "A1.$.A2": "some value" }})
```

I haven't actually tried this (I'm not in front of a Mongo instance right now) and I'm going off memory, but that should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $push can be used to do the same. Try below given code.

```
db.c.update({ A1: value }, { $push: { "A1.$.A2": num }});
```