# MongoDB how do I make an array with custom keys containing subdocument

Tags: python, mongodb, subdocument

Alright so using Python and MongoDB I am trying to embed a subdocument within an array with a custom key value in the array. I was playing around with all sorts of different ways to do this and I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong so I temporarily settled on the working code below. Numerous attempts always lead to the error:

> in _check_write_command_response
>       raise OperationFailure(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error) pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The dotted field 'first.rule'
>   in 'followedBy..first.rule' is not valid for storage.

Code:

```
 citizens.update(
    {"_id" : userPush},
    {"$push": {"followedBy":[field[1], field[2], field[3], field[0]]}})
```

Produces:

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5…asfd"), 
            "uName" : "tim0", 
            "fName" : "tim",
            "lName" : "lost",
            "pic" : null, 
            "bio" : "I <3 MongoDB", 
            "followedBy" : [
                [
                    "BobTheBomb", 
                    "bobby", 
                    "knight", 
                    NumberInt(2)
                ], 
                [
                    "Robert", 
                    "DROP", 
                    "TABLE", 
                    NumberInt(6)
                ]
```

This is what I want:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5…asfd"), 
    "uName" : "tim0", 
    "fName" : "tim",
    "lName" : "lost",
    "pic" : null, 
    "bio" : "I <3 MongoDB", 
    "followedBy" : [
            "BobTheBomb": { 
                    "fName" : "bobby", 
                    "lName" : "knight", 
                    "uID" : NumberInt(2)
        }, 
            "Robert": { 
                    "fName" : " DROP ", 
                    "lName" : " TABLE ", 
                    "uID" : NumberInt(6)
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build that data structure, currently you are saying that `"followedBy"` is only a list.

so try:

```
citizens.update(
    {"_id" : userPush},
    {"$push": {"followedBy":{field[1]: { "fName":field[2], "lName":field[3], "uID":field[0]}}}})
```

Remove the list and replace it with a dict.

I do hope this helps.

---

I have realised that I have not given you valid `json`, I have tested this:

```
citizens.update(
    {"_id" : userPush},
    {$push: 
    {"followedBy":
        [
            {field[1]: 
                { "fName": field[2], "lName": field[3], "uID": field[0]}
            }
        ]
    } 
})
```

And it worked...

---

You might find that the error is caused by the modifier you are using, I found the following on a [blog](http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/01/moving-along-with-pymongo.html):

> MongoDB provides several different modifiers you can use to update documents in place, including the following (for more details see [updates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)):
>
> ```
> - $inc Increment a numeric field (generalized; can increment by any number)
> - $set Set certain fields to new values
> - $unset Remove a field from the document
> - $push Append a value onto an array in the document
> - $pushAll Append several values onto an array
> - $addToSet Add a value to an array if and only if it does not already exist
> - $pop Remove the last (or first) value of an array
> - $pull Remove all occurrences of a value from an array
> - $pullAll Remove all occurrences of any of a set of values from an array
> - $rename Rename a field
> - $bit Bitwise updates
> ```

you might find that because you are inserting many items that you would rather want to use `$pushAll` or `$addToSet` rather than `$push`... Just a speculation...

Comment: It returned "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The dotted field 'first.rule' in 'followedBy..0.first.rule' is not valid for storage." I kept running into that error early, as well as several other when I tried tweaking it.

Comment: That produces the literal strings "field[1]". Output:  
"followedBy" : [
        {
            "field[1]" : {
                "uID" : "field[0]", 
                "fName" : "field[2]", 
                "lName" : "field[3]"
            }

Comment: oh sorry about that.. I used the string values to test the output - try the updated one

Comment: No you are fine, I really appreciate the help. I tried the updated code and it is still giving me the stubborn error:  "in _check_write_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The dotted field 'first.rule' in 'followedBy..first.rule' is not valid for storage." I am going to go to bed and give it another shot tomorrow. Thank you for the help

Comment: Still no luck, I am stuck on the same error and I do not understand the error

Comment: check out these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12784423/2173793, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19709624/2173793, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13894769/2173793, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041109/mongo-update-query-given-error. maybe one of them will help solve your issue. and can you please update your question with the full stacktrace?